# How to Upgrade Synology 2-Bay NAS Storage to Larger Capacity?

Tags: upgrade, synology, shr

First I'd like to apologize for the long read.

I hope you can help me with this one. I have a 2-bay NAS (DS218+). I initially have a single 4TB (WD Red NAS Drive) drive (SHR - without data protection) and multivolume support was flagged as No. I decided to upgrade my storage capacity so I bought a new 8TB WD Red NAS Drive.

I've been reading the knowledgebase but still reluctant to proceed as I'm still quite confused if I'm doing the correct procedure. What I want to achieve is to upgrade my storage without data loss to 8TB (without data protection in mind yet). **Lets just say I want to replace my 4TB to 8TB like nothing happened.**

The current version of my DSM is 6.2.3. In my 1st bay is the 4TB. I attached the 8TB to the 2nd bay and saw the drive recognized and "Not Initialized" as expected. Now, the videos I've seen always mention a **Manage** button, but in my case I can't find it. And it didn't ask me to repair anything nor there was a "Degrade" status.

I only see **Add Drive** when I go to **Storage Pool** -> **Action** however. I went with it and clicked Next, then had a pop up warning me that the data in the newly added drive will be erased, I clicked OK and this was displayed:

[image]

Now, the **Total Capacity: 3.63TB** is what got me bummed. I'm new to Raid stuff so I'm still quite confused. I'm hoping to get a new max capacity of 7.2TB from my new 8TB. How do I do this without losing data? And my system as-is?

I hope you can guide me. I'd really appreciate it.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To have redundancy you cannot have more than what can be saved on at least 2 disks. Right now you have only ~4TB available on 2 disks. If you have another 8TB you will be able to use 100% of the space.

More information

https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/Storage/What_is_Synology_Hybrid_RAID_SHR

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I only have 2-bay with initially a single 4TB. So meaning, I can't utilize the 8TB without backing up and starting over?

Comment: @user1865775 there is nothing you can do with 8TB + 4TB to have more than 4TB of redundancy... it's mathematically impossible.